# Two MOTD's - I want one of them disabled

Tags: 20.04, tty, motd, kali-linux-tools

I'm currently running Ubuntu 20.04.1 and I have some tools installed on it via Katoolin. I boot into TTY1 instead of using a GUI.

When I log in, I get two MOTD's. I want to get rid of one of them. I *think* I have a plan for resolving this but I'd appreciate a sanity check and - if I'm just completely off the mark - I'd like to be pointed in the right direction.

This is what they say:

**Message 1**

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-54-generic x86_64)
*Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com
*Management: https://landscape.canonical.com
*Support: https://ubuntu.com/advantage
10 updates can be installed immediately.
10 of these updates are security updates.
To see additional updates run: apt list --upgradable
Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2025.
Last login: Wed Dec 2 10:40:33 PST on tty1
```

**Message 2**

```
(Message from Kali developers)
This is a minimal installation of Kali Linux, you likely want to install supplementary tools. Learn how: https://www.kali.org/docs/troubleshooting/common-minimum/setup/


(Run "touch ~/.hushlogin" to hide this message)
```

I reviewed the link Kali suggested (http://kali.org/docs/troubleshooting/common-minimum-setup/) and it wasn't particularly helpful. It explained how to go from a minimal install to a fully functional desktop environment which I'm not interested in doing, and it mentioned Kali Network Repositories and Kali Branches which I'm also uninterested in.

I can see that Message 1 is being created by a dynamic MOTD file in /run, and I can see that the Kali MOTD is being generated by a file in /usr/bin.

Here's where I could use clarification - will running "touch ~/.hushlogin" also disable my dynamic MOTD? I don't want the dynamic MOTD disabled. I only want the Kali MOTD disabled.

If "touch ~/.hughlogin" can't do what I want, what are my options?

It seems like somewhere there's a configuration file calling up both MOTD's and I'd like to disable it there if I can rather than rm the kali-motd file from /usr/bin.

Comment: Kali is off topic here.

Comment: I'm not asking about Kali. I'm asking about configuring MOTD's and one of them comes from Kali but the question isn't about Kali.

Comment: Close vote retracted.

Comment: Message2 says `Run "touch ~/.hushlogin" to hide this message` ... did you try that ?

Comment: No. Again, I don't want to disable Ubuntu's dynamic MOTD, and I asked for clarification as to whether running "touch ~/.hushlogin" will also disable my dynamic MOTD. So, I was holding off on running that until that part of my question got answered.

Comment: it just stops the messages from displaying... you'll get a definitive answer once you do it... it's just as easy to remove ~/.hushlogin   (...unless this is a production system that you simply can't test with)

Comment: Right, but I'm asking if it only stops that one message I want disabled or if it will also stop the dynamic MOTD.

Comment: is there something preventing you from finding out? I you don't like the result remove the hushlogin?

Comment: I thought it was important to double-check what I had looked up before going forward with something I hadn't done before. I don't think there's a problem with asking the question I asked.

Answer (score 1):

One is the classic `/etc/motd` message.

The other one comes from the script in `/usr/bin/kali-motd`

which checks if there is a file for this user...

```
    if [ -e ~/.hushlogin ]; then
        return 0
```

so just:

```
touch ~/.hushlogin
```

and the dynamic motd.

Same for kali linux with the  "message from kali developers".

This will disabled that for this user.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best answer, but this is what worked.

With respect to the first part of the question - will running "touch ~/.hushlogin" also disable my dynamic MOTD - the answer is yes.

To remove the MOTD generated by Katoolin the fix was:

1. Navigate to /usr/bin
2. sudo cp kali-motd kali-motd.backup
3. sudo rm kali-motd
4. Navigate to /etc/profile.d
5. sudo cp kali.sh kali.sh.backup
6. sudo rm kali.sh